# Composer not looking to alternative VCS/Git Repo first

Tags: composer-php

I have the following in my composer.json, for bear/package it is picking up the alternative git repo, but not for bear/skeleton. For bear/skeleton it is getting the main repo checkout da04548 from packagist, rather than 6b3bd0ae16 from the github.com/mackstar account.

Does anyone know why this works for one repo and not the other?

Thanks in advance.

```
{
"name": "mackstar/spout",
"description":"A BEAR.Sunday based CMS",
"keywords":[
    "PHP",
    "CMS"
],
"authors":[
    {
        "name": "Richard McIntyre"
    }
],
"repositories": [

    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url":  "https://github.com/mackstar/BEAR.Skeleton"
    },
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url":  "https://github.com/mackstar/BEAR.Package"
    }
],
"require":{
    "php":">=5.4.0",
    "ext-curl":"*",
    "bear/resource":"0.9.*",
    "bear/skeleton":"dev-develop",
    "bear/package":"dev-develop",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the new bear/package [introduced a require](https://github.com/mackstar/BEAR.Skeleton/blob/develop/composer.json#L14) on `composer/installers` in version `dev-master`, which is not allowed by your minimum stability or requires, so that package can not be installed.

If you add `"composer/installers":"@dev"` to your requires or `"minimum-stability":"dev"` to the top level it should select the custom git repo for this package as well.